# How to upload comma-separated list from PDF file to MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I'm having a problem with uploading `PDF` file into a database. My script has to take uploaded files(`.csv`,`.pdf`,`.xcl`) which will contain user's basic information in form of comma-separated list and put it into adequate colummns in my users table.

I found way to do it with `.csv` files but I'm stuck with `.pdf` and `.xcl`:

This is what I have tried already:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
     $handle = fopen($file,"r");
     $line=file_get_contents($handle);
}
```

You can't imagine what this did to my table in database when I inserted it. I've read that it firstly needs to be parsed into a text file and then do something with it, but I have no idea how to do that. Please help if you have same experience with uploading this type of files.

Comment: Are you sure about PDF? I mean, it is not meant to be read as text, it was meant to be printed, hence the name Printed Document Format.

Comment: Yes but say that to my boss.. :D

Comment: @sfThomas it was meant to be Portable

Comment: Yes. You typically need some kind of pdf parser library - but a lot depends on exactly how the documents are constructed. It really is a little odd to provide a csv as a pdf.

Comment: @Strawberry - right, my mistake. Though it still was designed for printing, not for editing/reading.

Comment: How is the data in the PDF? In form fields, or as part of the contents?

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to help, but I solved my problem :)